# Adding one character to string

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

In C++:

If I want to add `0x01` to the string text I would do: `text += (char)0x01`;

If I want to add `0x02` to the string text I would do: `text += (char)0x02`;

If I want to add `0x0i` (were `i` is an unsinged `int` between 0 and 9), what could I do?

EDIT: I probably wasn't quite clear. So by 0x01, I mean the character given in Hex as 01. So in the above if i is the integer (in decimal) say 3, then I would want to add 0x03 (so this is not the character given in decimal as 48 + 3).

Comment: What is the type of `text`? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @dirkgently: text is a string. So I want to add too the string (i.e. make it longer by one character) the character given in hex by 0i.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly do

```
text += (char)i;
```

Because `0x0i == i` if `i` is between 0 and 9.

Answer (score 1):

One other possibility -- you could use `push_back` instead. Since it takes the string's `char_type` as its parameter type, you don't need an explicit cast:

```
text.push_back(i);
```

In fairness, I should add that you don't really need an explicit cast with `+=` either. Simply `text += i;` will work fine. For example:

```
std::string text; 
for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
     text += i;
```

With either `text += i;` or `text.push_back(i);`, this will produce a string that contains: "\x00\x01\x02\x03".

Answer (score 0):

You should generate its ASCII value. `'0'` is 48 and `'9'` is 9 + 48

```
text += (char)( i + 48 ) ;
```

if `i` was a multi digit number you could parse it to its digits and use the same technique to generate its equal string.

Comment: He doesn't want `'i'`, he wants `i`, so there's no need to add to 48. That's why his samples are `text += (char)0x01`, and not `text += (char)0x01+48`

Comment: If you are right, so what's the point of this question ? I think his first 2 lines are not correct. He wanted to concatenate characters but his hexadecimal numbers says you are right.